# How object class non Null works

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Can someone explain the following code?

```
if (Objects.nonNull(department.getDepartmentName()) && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(department.getDepartmentName())) {
    depDB.setDepartmentName(department.getDepartmentName());
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. What part is not clear to you?

Comment: That's what official documentation is for and why it should always be your first source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object- - **"Returns true if the provided reference is non-null otherwise returns false."** is pretty descriptive, so what more do you need to know about how that method works?

Answer (score 0):

The first stab at understanding how a piece of code works should be look at the documentation available.

[image: Documentation for Objects.isNonNull]

In your context, code intends to check if `department.getDepartmentName()` is **both** not-null and an empty string, only then set it to some value.

On an additional note, double check is redundant.

```
"".equalsIgnoreCase(department.getDepartmentName())
```

checks both, if `department.getDepartmentName()` is not null **and** is blank string.